# How to do when entering data to the next input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to do when entering data to the next input, and if I remove the data, it returns back to the input?

```
<input id="first" maxlength="1" value="">
<input id="second" maxlength="1" value="">
<input id="third" maxlength="1" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on the first empty input is pretty easy, but automatically moving back when the input is emptied feels counter-intuitive... If you want, you could add a keyup handler looking at whether the user is entering a backspace in an empty input; if they are, move the focus back.

That said, what's the reason for using three inputboxes instead of one? :)

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input-grouped");

function alwaysFocusFirstEmptyInput(event) {
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].value === "") {
      inputs[i].focus();
      break;
    }
  }
}

[...inputs].forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("input", alwaysFocusFirstEmptyInput, null);
});
```

```html
<input class="input-grouped" id="first" maxlength="1" value="">
<input class="input-grouped" id="second" maxlength="1" value="">
<input class="input-grouped" id="third" maxlength="1" value="">
```